# Using noise_shape of the Dropout layer. Batch_size does not fit into provided samples. What to do?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dropout

I am using a dropout layer in my model. As I use temporal data, I want the *noise_shape* to be the same per *timestep* -> (batch_size, 1, features).

The problem is if I use a batch size that does not fit into the provided samples, I get an error message. Example: *batch_size*= 2, samples= 7. In the last iteration, the *batch_size* (2) is larger  than the rest of the samples (1)

The other layers (my case: Masking, Dense, and LSTM) apparently don`t have a problem with that and just use a smaller batch for the last, not fitting, samples.

ConcreteError:
Training data shape is:[23, 300, 34]
batchsize=3

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes:
>   [2,300,34] vs. [3,1,34]    [[Node: dropout_18/cond/dropout/mul =
>   Mul[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](dropout_18/cond/dropout/div,
>   dropout_18/cond/dropout/Floor)]]

Meaning that for the last batch [**2**,300,34], the batch_size cannot split up into [**3**,1,34]

As I am still in the parameter tuning phase (does that ever stop :-) ),

- Lookback(using LSTMs),
- split-percentage of train/val/test,
- and batchsize

will still constantly change. All of the mentioned influence the actual length and shape of the Training data.

I could try to always find the next fitting int for *batch_size* by some calculations. Example, if *batch_size*=4 and samples=21, I could reduce *batch_size* to 3. But if the number of training samples are e.g. primes this again would not work. Also If I choose 4, I probably would like to have 4.

Do I think to complex? Is there a simple solution without a lot of exception programming?

Thank you

Comment: Most people just drop the last batch if it cannot be made to fit the required shape. Alternatively you can make your dropout layer depend on the runtime batch size (using tf.shape) instead of the static batch size.

Comment: Dear Alexandre, thanks for the suggestions. I, unfortunately, cannot drop any pinch of data as our dataset is already limited in size. We also have to look over a more long timestep, therefore, dropping one batch would mean dropping a significant amount of data.
Therefore, I will look into the runtime batch size. That makes actually sense. This will probably also be profitable for the other model layers. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to nuric in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873615/how-to-obtain-the-runtime-batch-size-of-a-keras-model), the answer is quite simple.

> The current implementation does adjust the according to the runtime
>   batch size. From the Dropout layer implementation code:
>
> ```
>  symbolic_shape = K.shape(inputs) noise_shape = [symbolic_shape[axis]
>  if shape is None else shape
>                 for axis, shape in enumerate(self.noise_shape)]
> ```
>
> So if you give `noise_shape=(None, 1, features)` the shape will be
>   (runtime_batchsize, 1, features)  following the code above.