# Neat way to pass list of arbitrary length to a custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have to build a special type of neural network in Keras which at some point of layer accepts an multi-dimensional array with N rows and 5 elements in each row. Let's refer to this multi-dimensional array as **bboxes**. **bboxes** looks like this:

```
[[  0, x1, x2, y1, y2] # row 0
 ...
 [  0, x1, x2, y1, y2]] # row N
```

So as you see, amount of rows is uncertain. All we know is that it is array full of rows where each row contains **5** integers.

Hence I could create a following input for **bboxes**:

```
from keras.layers import Input

bboxes = Input(shape=(None, 5), dtype='int32', name='bboxes')
```

---

## Problem:

I have to pass **bboxes** to a custom layer called **MyLayer**, which at some line of call method needs to get amount of rows in **bboxes**:

```
from keras.engine.topology import Layer

class MyLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    ...

    def call(x):
        ...
        N = x.shape[0]  # Get amount of rows (N) of bboxes
        ...
    ...
```

But as you may already know, Keras has a specific type of architecture which is defined by empty shapes  objects at first.

The actual integer `N` value, is passed after the model is compiled. So instead of integer `N`, It returns `?`, which is basically an empty tensor...

But `N = x.shape[0]` variable as an integer is important for `MyLayer` to work properly. I might do something like `range(0, N)` which will return the following error:

> **TypeError: int should return int object**

I am very confused about Keras functional API when it comes to such concerns. Is there any neat way I can pass array `bboxes` with arbitrarily defined row count (`N`) to `MyLayer` which will later use the actual value of `N`?

**In short**, how do I pass input with shape (N, 5) to a layer, so that layer knows the exact number of N?

I would greatly appreciate if there's any kind of way of solving this. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873615/how-to-obtain-the-runtime-batch-size-of-a-keras-model

Comment: @abdullah.cu Could you elaborate please? I have been unfortunately unable to find relevant answer in the post that might be useful for this question.